# C++ Segregated Free Lists

Tags: c++

I need to use segregated free lists for a homework assignment and I was wondering if the STL or some other library had these already written so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think STL has anything, but it looks like the Boost library might have it, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/simple_segregated_storage.html

Answer (score 0):

The STL implementations I've used support an allocator as a template parameter, which you could use to make a container **use** your segregated free list, but you'd still be writing your own.